# How to change XML with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

So I have some XML and I want the same XML but with a few lines gone. Here's my original XML :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Customers>
  <Customer>
    <FirstName>Sarah</FirstName>
    <LastName>Bellum</LastName>
    <PhoneNumbers>
      <PhoneNumber type="HOME">
        223 704 2215
      </PhoneNumber>
      <PhoneNumber type="WORK">
        223 704 1234
      </PhoneNumber>
      <PhoneNumber type="CELL">
        860 704 1234
      </PhoneNumber>
    </PhoneNumbers>
    <Addresses>
      <Address type="HOME">
        <Line1>123 Main</Line1>
        <Line2></Line2>
        <Line3></Line3>
        <City>Wallingford</City>
        <State>CT</State>
        <Zip>12345</Zip>
      </Address>
      <Address type="WOKR">
        <Line1>456 Main</Line1>
        <Line2></Line2>
        <Line3></Line3>
        <City>Willington</City>
        <State>CT</State>
        <Zip>12345</Zip>
      </Address>
    </Addresses>
  </Customer>

  <Customer>
    <FirstName>Mike</FirstName>
    <LastName>Easter</LastName>
    <PhoneNumbers>
      <PhoneNumber type="CELL">
        123 704 4321
      </PhoneNumber>
    </PhoneNumbers>
    <Addresses>
      <Address type="HOME">
        <Line1>14 East</Line1>
        <Line2></Line2>
        <Line3></Line3>
        <City>Shelton</City>
        <State>CT</State>
        <Zip>12345</Zip>
      </Address>
    </Addresses>
  </Customer>
</Customers>
```

and here is my target XML :

```
 ﻿<Customers>
  <Customer>
    <Name>Sarah Bellum</Name>
    <!-- This element should only appear if the source element exists -->
    <HomePhone>223 704 2215</HomePhone>
    <!-- This element should only appear if the source element exists -->
    <WorkPhone>223 704 1234</WorkPhone>
    <!-- This element should only appear if the source element exists -->
    <CellPhone>860 704 1234</CellPhone>
    <!-- This element should only appear if the source element exists -->
    <HomeAddress>
      <Street>123 Main</Street>
      <City>Wallingford</City>
      <State>CT</State>
      <Zip>12345</Zip>
    </HomeAddress>
    <!-- This element should only appear if the source element exists -->
    <WorkAddress>
      <Street>456 Main</Street>
      <City>Willington</City>
      <State>CT</State>
      <Zip>12345</Zip>
    </WorkAddress>
  </Customer>

  <Customer>
    <Name>Mike Easter</Name>
    <CellPhone>123 704 4321</CellPhone>
    <HomeAddress>
      <Street>14 East</Street>
      <City>Shelton</City>
      <State>CT</State>
      <Zip>12345</Zip>
    </HomeAddress>
  </Customer>
</Customers>
```

I have some XSLT but it just copies it and I want some lines gone. Here is my XSLT :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So I gave you the target XML and the original and some XSL. I don't know how to get rid of lines so can you pls help.

Comment: What you've posted as your `XSL` is a copy/paste of an identity template that only "transforms" the XML output into an identical copy of the input. I see you're new to the site; the best way to get help here on SO is to share what you've tried, and not just ask for someone to code a solution for you. It appears one of the main goals with your transform is to create new elements with new names that map to nodes in your input XML; have you tried anything to create those new elements?

Answer (score 1):

Well, some of the transformation rules here are easy, for example

```
<xsl:template match="FirstName">
 <Name><xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ', ../LastName)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LastName"/>
```

or

```
<xsl:template match="Phone[@type='CELL']">
  <CellPhone><xsl:value-of select="."/></CellPhone>
</xsl:template>
```

Others are more more difficult; I don't know how you decide which line of the input address is the Street.

But basically, what is your question? What exactly is the difficulty you are facing with this transformation? On the face of it, there isn't anything here that isn't covered in any "Beginning XSLT" textbook.